# In-App Purchase in Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Are in-app purchases allowed in Google Glass?  I've got some code I'm ready to try out with my existing android merchant account, but I don't want to get it banned or something.  Is this permitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears this is **NOT** permitted (at least in most cases). In **Section F. Fees** of the [Glass Platform Developer Policies](https://developers.google.com/glass/policies#Fees) it says:

```
You may not charge end users any fees or collect any payments 
in order to download or access your Glassware, or in 
connection with virtual goods or functionality of your Glassware.
```

One has to assume this extends to in-app purchases since these are most likely 'virtual goods'.  If you were Amazon.com selling physical products via Google Glass it might be interpreted differently.

Comment: I was looking at selling virtual goods, thanks for the pointer.